# Content Offset Not Updating in Swift

Tags: swift, uiscrollview

I have an app in Swift 4.0 in which I have a wide scrollview containing multiple images that are each as wide as the screen. Currently the user can swipe through them, which works perfectly. I'm in the process of adding buttons for paging left and right. The code for one of the buttons is below (the left button has the same structure).

When I use the buttons to page right or left, the content offset does not change at all. For example, if I start out on page #1, the horizontal content offset is 0. When I run the scrollRight function, the content offset remains 0, even though it's showing page #2 (it prints "content offset = 0"). If I swipe instead, it displays page #2, but the content offset updates to UIScreen.main.bounds.width (it prints "content offset = 414")

```
func scrollRight(){
    let currentX = sectionScroll.contentOffset.x
    let newX = currentX + UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    sectionScroll.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: newX, y: 0), animated: true)
    print("content offset= ", sectionScroll.contentOffset.x)
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Do I just not understand how UIScrollViews function? Is there a way to use the button to display the next page and also update the content offset in the same way that scrolling would? I end up using the content offset in later code to determine which page the user is looking at, so I'd like it to be able to update whether the user swipes or clicks through the pages.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in case anyone else runs into a similar issue.

When the animation is set to "true", it takes time to move to the new offset. Therefore, you have to take that into account-- I just built in a short delay before running the rest of my code, although I'm sure there are other ways around it.